# I have a nested composable, I want to use a utility class with it, I want it to be mockable and prevent recomposition on its initialization

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following Composable heirarchy:

```
DashboardComposable
-> Recommendation(viewModel: RecommendationViewModel = hiltViewModel())
  -> Recommendation(uiState: RecommendationUiState)
   -> LazyColumn {  
        RecommendationItem(item: Recommendation) // Within the composable RecommendationItem, I want to use a discount calculator
      }
```

As shown above, I need to use an instance of discount calculator in my Recommendation Item.
I think I have following options

1. If I create variable inside the RecommendationItem composable, it will be re-initialized again and again
2. If I pass it from DashboardComposable, it will consume unnecessary amount of memory and voilates the scoping
3. If I use produceState or LaunchedEffect, I cannot mock it. Cause in order to mock it I will need to pass it through the constructor
4. Problem with keeping calculator in viewModel and making every child composable have it as a param causes issues in preview and it also doesn't make sense for an Item Composable to depend on a viewmodel it can depend on a simple data class

For now, I have computed properties in recommendaiton class which solved only for this case.

```kotlin
class Recommendation {
   val discountedPrice: Double
      get() {
      }
}
```

But I am migrating my whole project. I can imagine that there are a lot of places in my project in which I will need to depend on utility class

Any suggestions on how to pull this off correctly?